# gnuplot doesn't show plotting window on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

[image: error from wxt]

I was using gnuplot in Ubuntu with wxt terminal, and when I type in `plot sin(x)`, I get an error message:

Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
23:00:40: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?
Failed to initialize wxWidgets.

Comment: Is this real Ubuntu - or Ubuntu via Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Comment: By default, `gnuplot` expects a graphical environment. In `gnuplot`, `help set terminal` will show other choices.

Comment: @steeldriver I'm using Ubuntu in a box on windows- I actually didn't know WSL has Ubuntu...

Comment: @waltinator    Yeah, I tried some other terminals, fig and png for example, but they either showed me a block of numbers or some garbled characters, and there's no plotting window.

Comment: `fig` and `png` are *file formats* - you will need to redirect their terminal output to a file, which you may then copy to and view in your Windows GUI if your Ubuntu system is CLI only.

Comment: In `gnuplot`, `help set output` and `help set`and `help`.